# SQLAlchemy: Labeling a union of two queries based on column index?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this code currently:

```
qbc_q = cmdata_sess.query(cast(QBConfiguration.id, Text).label("cfg_id"),
                          QBConfiguration.branch.label("branch"),
                          QBConfiguration.description.label(
                              "cfg_description"),
                          QBConfiguration.name.label("cfg_name"))
tcc_q = cmdata_sess.query(TCConfiguration.id.label("cfg_id"),
                          TCConfiguration.branch.label("branch"),
                          TCConfiguration.name.label('cfg_description'),
                          TCConfiguration.name.label("cfg_name"))
configs_subq = qbc_q.union(tcc_q).subquery("config")
```

As you can see, the labeling is quite redundant. As an example, I would like to somehow be able to say:

```
configs_subq.labels(["cfg_id", "branch", "cfg_description", "cfg_name"])
```

Is there a way I can make this code more concise?